# Error: Template Does Not Exist

Tags: python, django, url, view

I have two apps in one project the main apps call pages contain Home and About page the second apps is contact page.
Here is my contact/urls.py in contact apps:

```
from .views import ContactFormView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       # URL pattern for the ContactView
                       url(regex=r'^contact/$', view=ContactFormView.as_view(), name='contact'),
)
```

the main apps pages/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import AboutPageView, HomePageView


urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(regex=r'^$', view=HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
                       url(regex=r'^about/$', view=AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),

)
```

in main apps pages/views.py :

```
from vanilla import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/home.jade"

class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/about.jade"

class ContactFormView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "contact/email_form.jade"
```

I get this error say django.template.base.TemplateDoesNotExist

TemplateDoesNotExist: /contact/email_form.jade

I am not sure why, the setting file is OK I can open the main page with the contact page in the menu nav when I click contact I get the error above. Any helps appreciate 
Thanks

Comment: Please show your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the email_form.jade file inside /templates/contact.  Or place it in /templates/pages and change the line to template_name = "pages/email_form.jade".

Comment: Many thanks for your answer I have changed all still not working but have changed to template_name = 'contact/email_form.jade' now it work the reason is the email_form.jade in in template inside contact apps. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you don't have the any of the parent directories the template is in marked as `static` in `app.yaml`.

App Engine stores and serves static files separately from application files. Static files are not available in the application's file system.

If you do either find a separate directory to place static files or you can optionally use

`application_readable: True` in the configuration block for static files which allows the filesystem to read them.

[See here for more details](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers)